# My strategy.entry() is not executing at all

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, back-testing, pine-script-v5

I've just recently started pine scrip and I wrote this code backtest a strategy, however the strategy.entry() function seems not to be working. I've even changed it such that it has nothing to do with the rest of the code at all and it still doesn't work. I'm wondering if anyone knows what might be stopping my strategy.entry() to not working at all.

```
strategy("Higher High", overlay=true, calc_on_every_tick=true, initial_capital=5000, currency='USD', commission_type=strategy.commission.cash_per_order, commission_value=10, pyramiding=50)
Period = input.int(7,"Pivot Point Period", minval = 1)
showSR = input(defval = true, title="Show Support/Resistance Level Extensions")
showPP = input(defval = true, title="Show Pivot Points Labels")
ShowFB = input(true, title="Show Fractal Break Arrows")

float pivotHigh = na //swing high
float pivotLow = na //swing low
pivotHigh := ta.pivothigh(Period, Period)
pivotLow := ta.pivotlow(Period, Period)

valuewhen_1 = ta.valuewhen(pivotHigh, high[Period], 1) // return the most recent occurence of a condition; in this case, the most 2nd recent time (so the last-last time) there was a pivot high
valuewhen_2 = ta.valuewhen(pivotHigh, high[Period], 0) //returns the most recent pivot high
higherhigh = na(pivotHigh) ? na : valuewhen_1 < valuewhen_2 ? pivotHigh : na //higher high returns the price of the most recent pivot high IF it is greater than the last pivot high
lowerhigh = na(pivotHigh) ? na : valuewhen_1 > valuewhen_2 ? pivotHigh : na
valuewhen_3 = ta.valuewhen(pivotLow, low[Period], 1)
valuewhen_4 = ta.valuewhen(pivotLow, low[Period], 0)
higherlow = na(pivotLow) ? na : valuewhen_3 < valuewhen_4 ? pivotLow : na
lowerlow = na(pivotLow) ? na : valuewhen_3 > valuewhen_4 ? pivotLow : na
////////////////


upTrend = close > high[1]
strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, qty=10, when=upTrend, limit=close, comment = 'Long', oca_name = 'x', oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel)


////////////////
plotshape(showPP ? higherhigh  : na, title='HH', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.green,50), text="HH",textcolor=color.new(color.green,50),offset = -Period)
plotshape(showPP ? higherlow  : na, title='HL', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green,50), text="HL",textcolor=color.new(color.green,50),offset = -Period)
plotshape(showPP ? lowerhigh  : na, title='LH', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red,50), text="LH",textcolor=color.new(color.red,50),offset = -Period)
plotshape(showPP ? lowerlow  : na, title='LL', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.red,50), text="LL",textcolor=color.new(color.red,50),offset = -Period)

///showing the resistance and support (of pivot points)

float resistance = na
float support    = na
support    := pivotLow  ? pivotLow  : support[1]
resistance := pivotHigh ? pivotHigh : resistance[1]

plot(showSR and support    ? support    : na, color = showSR and support    ? color.new(color.teal,50) : na, style = plot.style_circles, offset = -Period)
plot(showSR and resistance ? resistance : na, color = showSR and resistance ? color.new(color.red,50)  : na, style = plot.style_circles, offset = -Period)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fireshot, you only have entry calls in this strategy. Trades are executing, but we cannot calculate trades without closed trades. I have 50 open positions after pyramiding to your limit, they we have held since as we need to use strategy.exit, or strategy.close to exit a trade